# How to register object to ArrayList during creation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am dynamically creating tree with nodes of type A,B and C. Which node is created is chosen during execution.
For example tree:
!(https://ibb.co/F8qX9dW)

I also want to have ArrayList with all created nodes of type C. (In the end - tree is very huge, places where node C can be created is a lot, real number of node type C is not enough - so its not optimal for visiting whole tree every time I need work with this nodes)

My question is: Is possible in constructor of class C also save this object to mentioned arraylist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - given a non-null `List<C> cs`, pass that list to `C`'s constructor so it can add itself to the list.  For example:

```
    List<C> cs = new ArrayList<>();
    C c = new C(1, cs);
    System.out.println(cs.size());
    System.out.println(cs.get(0) == c);
```

where `C`'s constructor including the list as a parameter:

```
public class C
{
    public C(int someInt, @NotNull List<C> cList) {
        // assign field values, etc.
        cList.add(this);  // add self to the list
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I like the above though, since it makes `C` aware (even briefly) of an external entity (the list).  Perhaps there should be an overall wrapper for the Tree, so the wrapper can manage it:

```
public class Tree {
    private RealTree delegate = new RealTree(); 
    private List<C> cs = new ArrayList<>();

    public void Add(A a) {
       delegate.Add(a);
    }

    public void Add(B b) {
       delegate.Add(b);
    }

    public void Add(C c) {
       delegate.Add(c);
       cs.Add(c)
    }
}
```

This might make it easier to remove `C` nodes as well.